# Solidity smart contract interacting with deployed smartcontract

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereumjs

Below are the steps (take note, no issues when I test this on remix, it works absolutely fine)

1. Two smart contracts, Usermapping.sol and CoffeeNetworking.sol

   2. in truffle "2_deploy_contract.js" enable Usermapping.sol inorder to deploy Usermapping.sol contract
   3. Then get the address of the Usermapping.sol of deployed contract.
   4. Go to etherscan and convert the address to upper case.(if i dont do this step truffle compiler throws an error on invalid checksum address)
   5. Update the newly converted address in to CoffeeNetworking.sol.
   6. Then update truffle file "2_deploy_contract.js" to disbale Usermapping.sol deploy configuration and update with CoffeeNetowking.sol.
   7. Then finally truffle migrate for CoffeeNetworking.sol, no issues on deployment.
2. For interaction, truffle console --network dev
3. When i execute below function in truffle console, transaction goes through, `CoffeeNetworking.at('0xfd95F4AF776ba4F0E6D13fEc18763cA59336494c').then(function(instance){ return instance.addValue(25)}).then(function(result){ console.log("Result", result) })`
4. In order to get the set value of above funciton, i execute below function, but could nt see the value of 25 result. (no issues if i use directly Usermapping.at(usermappingaddress) to execute the same funciton `CoffeeNetworking.at('0xfd95F4AF776ba4F0E6D13fEc18763cA59336494c').then(function(instance){ return instance.getValue()}).then(function(result){ console.log("Result", result) })`

//Usermapping.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;
        contract Usermapping {
            uint256 public value;
            bytes32 public name;
            function addValue(uint a) public returns (bool)
            {
                value = a;
                return true;
            }
            function getValue() public view returns(uint256)
            {
                return value;
            }
            function setName(bytes32 nameSet) public returns(bool){
                name = nameSet;
                return true;
            }
             function getName() public view returns(bytes32){
                return name;
            }
        }

        var B = artifacts.require("./Usermapping.sol");
          module.exports = function(deployer){
        deployer.deploy(B)
       }
```

//CoffeeNetowkring.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract CoffeeNetworking{ 
    Usermapping u  = Usermapping(0x9B3a12cF7D8560DCd3d5D148cDCBCb9E1617D06F); 
    uint256 public version =1;
    // address add = 0x9B3a12cF7D8560DCd3d5D148cDCBCb9E1617D06F;  

    constructor () public {
    //   u = Usermapping(0xE1D685Fb942903986A9639da688d62E463BFC0DB);  
    }

    function addValue(uint a) public returns (bool){
        // Usermapping u = Usermapping(add);
        return u.addValue(a);
    }

    function getValue() public view returns (uint256){
        // Usermapping u = Usermapping(add);
        return u.getValue();
    }

    function setName(bytes32 name) public returns(bool){
        // Usermapping u = Usermapping(add);
        return u.setName(name);
    }

     function getName() public view returns(bytes32){
        // Usermapping u = Usermapping(add);
        return u.getName();
    }

}

contract Usermapping {
    uint256 public value;
    bytes32 public name;
    function addValue(uint a) public returns (bool);
    function getValue() public view returns(uint256);
    function setName(bytes32 nameSet) public returns(bool);
    function getName() public view returns(bytes32);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`geth` is returning transaction hash and `remix` is returning value. This is a fundamental difference in behavior of `geth` and `remix`.
Transactions don’t return a contract value to the front end because transactions are not immediately mined and included in the blockchain.
To get values from a function either you should use solidity events or you should use calls in Ethereum.

Refer [this](https://blog.b9lab.com/calls-vs-transactions-in-ethereum-smart-contracts-62d6b17d0bc2) blog to understand more about calls and transactions in solidity.

Refer to [this](https://media.consensys.net/technical-introduction-to-events-and-logs-in-ethereum-a074d65dd61e)  blog for understanding more about solidity events.